# Scala: How to make a field visible for subclasses, but not visible for their inner classes?

Tags: scala, visibility, modifiers

How can I make a field visible for subclasses, but not visible for their inner classes?

```
class Foo

class Parent {
  protected val x = 5
} 

class Sub extends Parent {
  println(x) // 5

  new Foo {
    println(x) // it's 5, but I want it to be a compiler error...
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Lexical nesting is kind of an important thing in Scala. But hey, there's lots of things you can do, maybe someone will surprise me.

Comment: It might also be important to recognize that new Foo doesn't refer to an Inner Class because it is merely instantiated within Sub - it is not defined there. Because of that, the x in Sub's new Foo is actually not Foo having access to Parent's x. It is Sub accessing Parent's x while he is instantiating a new Foo. I hope that makes some sense. Note that you cannot define Foo as class Foo{ def y = x } because x is not available.